# Ckecked box value in array in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have following html code, for this i want php code which take value of selected checked box.

```
<div class="right_info">
    <div class="tabs_btn">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="btn" href="">bio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="">images</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="">map</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="banner-fade">

        <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
        <ul class="bjqs">
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="1"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="2"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="3"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="4"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="5"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="6"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="7"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="8"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="9"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="10"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="11"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="12"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="13"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="14"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="15"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="16"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="17"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="18"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="19"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="20"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="21"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="22"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="23"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="24"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="25"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="imagename[]" value="26"><span>selected</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

    </div>


    <?php $doc=n ew DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTML('
    <ul class="bjqs">'); $liList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input'); $liValues = array(); foreach ($liList as $li) { $liValues[] = $li->nodeValue; } var_dump($liValues); ?>


</div>
```

please help me. i am using above php code but it is not selecting value. The button of the form is using jquery.

Comment: where is your button?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the PHP code at the bottom? Is that what you have done to select the checked boxes?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST['imagename'] as $imageval) {
    echo "Image #$imageval is selected.<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but i have to store all the selected value in array

Comment: You can put whatever you want in the body of the loop, that's just an example.

Comment: All the selected values are already in an array, `$_POST['imagename']`.

Answer (score 0):

put all your checkboxes in a `form` tag..
like

```
<form method="POST" action="your-action-page.php">
your checkbox tags here...
</form>
```

now in your action page..

```
if(isset($_POST['imagename']))
{
    print_r($_POST['imagename'])
}
```